# Inserting Duplicate Values in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, nodes, binary-search-tree

First of all I know this question has been asked **multiple times** so my apologies but I got lost when I thought of creating a BST for the word **'BERNER'** with **duplicates** allowed .

So I know this might look like this, I'm half way done with it but I got confused when I think about placing **N** and **R**

```
     B
    / \
   E   R
  /   
 E
```

Also I have some other questions

1. In the above BST the first *'E'* letter initially gets placed on the right side of the **root node (B)** due to *E>B*, but when we move on to *'R'* it becomes the right node and *'E'* becomes left node so I was thinking isn't that a violation of the BST rule since *E > B*, and it should also be a right node of *'B'* ?  Is this some kind of rule which I'm missing.
2. Creating 'BERNER' without Duplicates

Any help/Suggestion will be appreciated. Please don't be tough on me. I'm a newbie to BST Concepts.

Comment: E is larger than B and therefor should be the right child of B.

Comment: That's what my confusion is, so there should be 2 right nodes of B ?

Comment: Because B is the smallest letter it must be the leftmost letter; the other five letters go to the right of B.

Comment: @DanielBruckner I think I figured out but still need your suggestion on this. [BST with Duplicates Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YEedjghWKuSlU0Q1A1M2owRnc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: BST for BERNER, with consideration that there is no different to insert nodes to left or right when its value is equal to its parent]

Binary Tree for BERNER (PLEASE PAY ATTENTION that There must be no duplicate nodes in BST), with consideration that there is no different to insert nodes to left or right when its value is equal to its parent.

Comment: Thanksm I think your answer seems to be more correct than mine, but still I would love to hear some feedback on these [two possible BST's](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_YEedjghWKuSlU0Q1A1M2owRnc/edit) . Also I know very well that there must be no duplicate nodes in BST but the nature of the question says me to consider **If** duplicates are allowed.

Comment: I cant understand clearly that what is your problem? is it your homework?

Comment: No, its an interview question Well I think I will go with ur design of BST.

Comment: Basically they just said to me design a BST for the word 'BERNER' with duplicates allowed. Nothing more I told them duplicates is not a good way to create BST as it would reduce look up time and have other issues as well. But they said leave all of that and just create one with duplicates.